# iphone uitabviewcontroller

Tags: iphone

I want to have same segmented control across on all navigation tabs with segment value change delegate in it which refereshes currently selected tab data. . I dont want to create different sengemented control for each tab.

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Malleswar

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make your `UISegmentedControl` a peer of the `UITabBarController` view. So it would look like this:

```
 -------------------
|UISegmentedControl |
|-------------------|
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|UITabBarController |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
 -------------------
```

The key here is that your `UISegmentedControl` needs to not be a subview of the `UITabBarController` view, so I would create a separate `UIViewController` subclass that owns and lays out the `UISegmentedControl` and `UITabBarController` views.

Also, I'd recommend embedding the `UISegmentedControl` in a `UIToolBar`. That will look a lot better than placing it on a blank view.